# Is there a better way to count the number of records which fulfil conditions over two columns in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Sorry for the badly worded question, I'm struggling how best to put it into words. I'm looking to count the number of records in a database that are underage and have made an illegal purchase. The illegal purchases are buying wine and making bets (i.e gambling). I want to know how to count records that have done one OR the other OR both.

I tried COUNTIFS but that uses AND logic and I ended up double counting. So far I've managed it with a helper column but I'm not sure this is the best solution.

Using a small data set, I made a helper column and used OR to find age-restricted transactions. I then used COUNTIFS to find how many were made by underaged counts.

[image: Excel sheet with formulas used]

Is this a good way? I feel like a found a very roundabout way to do something that should be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--((B:B>YEAR(TODAY())-18)*(C:C+D:D)>0),0))
```

If you're using functions like SUM, COUNTIF, MAXIFS, etc., you can use addition for OR and multiplication for AND. Breaking down the pieces in the formula above:

- `(B:B>YEAR(TODAY())-18)` creates a array of TRUE/FALSE (T/F) values based on the dates.
- `(C:C+D:D)` adds together the Wine and Bets columns. This is like OR because you only get 0 (false) if both values are 0.
- `(B>YEAR)*(C+D)` multiplies the two values. Since this will be 0 if *either* term is 0, this is like the AND function for arrays.
- `(B>YEAR)*(C+D)>0`, then, returns a T/F array that is the real result of our pseudo-AND function.
- `--` coerces T/F into 1/0 by doing math: negative(negative(T/F)) makes Excel concert T/F into numerical equivalents.
- `IFERROR(~,0)` is there because with text values (like the headers) will throw an error so we ignore them by turning them into 0.
- `SUM(~)` adds up all the values which will all be 1 or 0 based on our pseudo function `AND(B>YEAR,OR(C,D))`.